# Can I check battery status of iPhone in background state?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need to check battery status in my applicaiton when it is in background state. I can check batter status in running state. Can NSNotificationCenter be used to check battery status in background? If yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible in two modes, which both keep your app alive. The first one is background audio, while you are playing music, your app will receive those notifications. The second one is background GPS tracking via Core Location.

If your app doesn't perform one of these, its state is frozen in memory and you won't receive any notification from the OS.

Comment: I think the third one is for connection test for VOIP. I just need clear answer whether it will be possible or not. Apple docs says background is possible for GPS location, Audio play and VOIP only, anyways thanks for ur reply

Comment: VOIP is just another audio background mode, so its still two modes. And like I said, you can do this as long as you in one of these two modes. If you are not, you just can't run in the background. Its that simple.

Comment: In my tests, background audio drains quite a bit of power. I've lost 20% of max battery charge over 8 hours after adding silent background audio!

Comment: how to constantly monitor the battery level when it is in background or suspended state? Not sure how these apps work.https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/batteria-hd-pro/id328670983?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

No, If you have background audio in your application app store will reject.